# Search 2 directories with loop and find duplicate files and remove one of them from one of 2 directories

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu

I have 2 directories(test1 and test2) with some file in their. How i can write a bash to find duplicate filename ane filesize from theise directories And remove one of them from one directory?

Comment: Typically something like `for f in dir1/*; do rm dir2/$(basename $f); done`. Adding a test for the size (`stat -c %s file`)  is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a command that should achieve what you want:

```
for f in test1/*; do find test2 -name $(basename $f) -size $(stat -c %s $f)c -delete; done
```

**Explanation:**

- `for f in test1/*`: Loop over each file in test1
- `$(basename $f)`: Return the base name of the file passed through by the loop
- `$(stat -c %s $f)`: Return the size of the file passed through by the loop
- The `c` at the end of the `stat` block is so the output is read as bytes by `find`
- `find test2 -name $(basename $f) -size $(stat -c %s $f)c -delete`: Find matching files and delete them with `-delete`

For a dry run omit the `-delete` flag.

Note: This wont work on MacOS because the built in `stat` command does not support the `-c` flag. Instead install the gnu version of stat.